# Problema al mostrar foto de perfil de Facebook en un ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy tratando de mostrar la imagen de perfil de Facebook en un ImageView cuando el usuario inicia sesión en la aplicación, el problema es que Glide solo carga la imagen por defecto de Facebook como se ve en la imagen:

[Imagen que muestra Glide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcDml.jpg)

Este es mi código:

Método onCreate:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null){
        goLoginScreen();
    }else {
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile != null){
            displayProfileInfo(profile);
        }else{
            Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Método displayProfileInfo:

```
private void displayProfileInfo(Profile profile){
    String name = profile.getName();
    String photoUrl = profile.getProfilePictureUri(100,100).toString();

    txtviewUname.setText(name);
    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(photoUrl).into(profileImage);
}
```

Comment: Te fijaste que el usuario tenga foto de perfil ?

Comment: ¿Probaste analizando la url obtenida dentro de un navegador para ver si carga la foto?